# Join for more than one table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sum, inner-join

I have a mssql database name Organization

I have 3 tables:

```
Table 1 named Organization
Table 2 named Product
Table 3 named IPAddress
```

Table 1 returns about 1000 results which is fine.

```
SELECT distinct OrganizationName, AssetNumber
FROM OrganizationList 
Where OrganizationName = 'orgname'
```

All I would like to see is the asset numbers with each org. Im not sure how to do this. I know a need a join and have tried a bunch of examples from the net however am not able to get it working.

Also I would like to be able to get the IPaddress for each asset

The problem i an running into is i need to match the `OrganizationID` col from Organization with the `OrganizationID` col from Product and i need to match the `ProductId` from Product and the `ProductId` from `IPAddress`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you will need any more info.

Thank You

Comment: You should post the all tables structures - the columns that each table have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should also list out the IP address for you as well.

```
SELECT distinct c1.OrganizationName, c2.AssetNumber, c3.IPAddress
FROM Organization c1

INNER JOIN Product c2
    ON c1.OrganizationID = c2.OrganizationID
INNER JOIN IPAddress c3
    ON c2.ProductId = c3.ProductId

Where c1.OrganizationName = 'orgname'
```

Comment: This query actually worked for most of everything i wanted. Can you tell me how to select distinct on just the IPAddress field? It is should be showing on 8 however shows 16 with duplicates.

Comment: What do you mean select distinct on just the IPAddress field.  The query is already selecting distinct IP addresses per organization and asset number.  Also, how does this differ from my answer which was submitted 19 minutes earlier?

Comment: @Linger Im not sure i tired to get yours to work and i kept getting an could not be bound on he AssetNumber and IPAddress feilds

Answer (score 0):

I am doing some guessing here since you didn't give us all of the information needed to fully help you.  How about the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.OrganizationName, p.AssetNumber, ip.IPaddress
FROM Organization AS o
  INNER JOIN Product AS p
  ON o.OrganizationID = p.OrganizationID
  INNER JOIN IPAddress AS ip 
  ON p.ProductId  = ip.ProductId
Where o.OrganizationName = 'orgname'
```

I didn't see any need to join the `OrganizationList` table.  If you do indeed need it then add the following join:

```
INNER JOIN OrganizationList AS ol
ON o.OrganizationID = ol.OrganizationID
```

Answer (score 0):

for user3022598
Take result of this query in a temp table:

SELECT distinct o.OrganizationName, p.AssetNumber, i.IPAddress
FROM Organization o

INNER JOIN Product p
    ON o.OrganizationID = p.OrganizationID
INNER JOIN IPAddress i
    ON p.ProductId = i.ProductId

Where o.OrganizationName = 'orgname'

then you can apply disctint on ipaddress field.

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

```
select o.OrgName, o.AssetNo
from OrgList o
join Prdct p 
on o.orgid = p.orgid
Union All
select p.productid/name, i.ipadress 
from product p
join ipadres i 
on p.prdid=i.prdid
```

Plz check it & let me know if works or not.

Comment: Union only works when the two tables have the exact same column structure